# Минификация исходного кода

Tags: html

Хотелось бы узнать, как компилировать исходный код web-страницы в одну строку. Что для этого нужно использовать?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы правильно употребляете слово «компилировать»?

Comment: "Что для этого нужно использовать?" - удаление лишних пробелов (ну вот серьезно). Эту штуку можно легко загуглить по запросу html minifier (аналогично существуют js minifier, css minifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать нужно html minifier. Однако, следует быть с этим осторожным, поскольку в случае, если в css прописано отображение с сохранением пробелов или переводов строк, минификация может это отображение попортить.

Обычно минифицируют только стили и скрипты.